# LG Ultrafine 5K firmware update ZIP search

Tags: macbook-pro, big-sur

Does anyone have access to the LG UltraFine 5K display firmware update ZIP file? LG ScreenManager doesn't recognize any update even though there should be one. LG support rejected me that they doesn't have access to it and this is on Apple side which is nonsense?
Can someone help me?